# Why avoid macros in HRESULT handling?

Tags: c++

Why would one choose to or not choose to use macros while defining error/HRESULT handling/logging?

I was approaching an error handling class called through an interface so I could use the Boost shared pointer to call the class when and where I needed it. (Quite honestly; I don't know if it's the best approach but I mostly wanted to see if I could do it and what it would look like). 
i.e:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<iErrorHandling> Error_Handler;

Error_Handler Err_Handler(new ErrHandling);

if (error)
{
    Err_Handler->vDX_ERR(ERR_D3D_INIT_SWAP);
}
```

I started using the class with DirectX and as DirectX requires a lot of HRESULT handling I was pointed towards using a macro to avoid all the if/else statements. I came across this:

```
#define lengthof(rg) (sizeof(rg)/sizeof(*rg))

inline const char* StringFromError(char* szErr, long nSize, long nErr)
{
    _ASSERTE(szErr);
    *szErr = 0;
    DWORD cb = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, nErr, 0, szErr, nSize, 0);
    char szUnk[] = "<unknown>";
    if( !cb && nSize >= lengthof(szUnk) ) lstrcpyA(szErr, szUnk);
    return szErr;
}

inline HRESULT TraceHR(const char* pszFile, long nLine, HRESULT hr)
{
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        char szErr[128];
        char sz[_MAX_PATH + lengthof(szErr) + 64];
        wsprintfA(sz, "%s(%d) : error 0x%x: %s\n", pszFile, nLine, hr,
            StringFromError(szErr, lengthof(szErr), hr));
        OutputDebugStringA(sz);
    }
    return hr;
}

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define TRACEHR(_hr) TraceHR(__FILE__, __LINE__, _hr)
#else
#define TRACEHR(_hr) _hr
#endif

#define HR(ex) { HRESULT _hr = ex; if(FAILED(_hr)) return TRACEHR(_hr), _hr; }
```

(From: https://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/a_young_person.htm)

While this looks great to me I've also found a few sites that describe macros as "evil" and that they should be used minimally.

Which method would perform better and why?
Is there another method I haven't discovered yet?

Additionally; Does it make sense to define macros with `__FILE__ __FUNC__ __LINE__` to create error log strings or is it acceptable to define your own specific errors and list them in a header file?

i.e:

```
 static LPTSTR ERR_D3D_INIT_HW =        __T("cD3D::Initialize: Failed to establish hardware.");
static LPTSTR ERR_D3D_INIT_SWAP =       __T("cD3D::Initialize: Failed to create the swap device.");
```

Which is better performance-wise regardless of how much time either method takes to implement?

Comment: Alexander Gessler is absolutely correct.  Macros are *not* intrinsically "evil", and your scenario is a good example of where macros are both appropriate and helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros are not inherently evil. However, they tend to make code hard to read and can cause hard-to-debug errors if used improperly. For these reasons, the general recommendation will always be in favor of less macros. What you've brought up are two very specific cases in which macros are fine.

- Log/trace macros that incorporate `__LINE__` et al are common and it is hard (/impossible) to achieve the same effect without macros. There is IMHO nothing wrong about them.
- `FAILED(hr)` like macros are also quite common and there is nothing wrong or hard to read about them. You could use a function instead and with today's compilers it would likely get inlined most of the time, but this has not always been the case. `FAILED` in particular is part of COM/DirectX for two decades and people are accustomed to parsing it.